# how fix a compile problem in tex studio

Tags: compiling

I dont know why my tex give me the messenge: "Error: Could not start the command: Compile & View"

how can i fix it?

edit: my package is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}

%Digitação de textos em português brasileiro, com codificação utf8
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%Informações autorais
\title{\textbf{Relatório 21/04}}
\author{Luiza Camile Rosa da Silva \\ luiza@ime.usp.br}
\date{15/04/2020}



%Pacotes com funções variadas (colunas, cores, gerador de texto, margens menores, identação correta)
\usepackage{multicol, xcolor, lipsum, a4wide, indentfirst,float,longtable}

%Pacotes matemáticos com formatação de números para o Brasil
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, siunitx,amsfonts,amscd}


\geometry{left=4cm,right=4cm,bottom=4cm,top=4cm}
\sisetup{
    group-separator = {.},
    group-digits = integer,
    group-minimum-digits = 3,
    output-decimal-marker = {,}
}

%Pacotes para uso de figuras
\usepackage{graphicx, psfrag}

%Pacote para geração de PDF's com links (não utilize com o modo DVI, apenas no modo PDF)
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%Pacotes para referências bibliográficas e índice remissivo
% LEMBRANDO SE PRECISAR DAS NORMAS ABNT NA REFERÊNCIA\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{definicao}{Definição}[section]
\newtheorem{exemplo}{Exemplo}[section]
\newtheorem{proposicao}{Proposição}[section]
\newtheorem{observacao}{Observação}[section]
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolário}[section]
\newtheorem{exercicio}{Exercício}[section]
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\makeindex 


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I knew that the problem isnt the code... And in the log, i just got badboxes...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We can't do much to help with the information you have provided. Anything else that you can add (new machine?, recent installation?, other recent changes, etc.) might give us a clue.

Comment: Please give the OP some time to improve his question before downvoting (the same goes for voting to close).

Comment: Is this a 4 page document that suddenly had this error?

Comment: i edited the post...

Comment: I just copied and pasted OP's code and generated a .pdf file without errors. I think it is a TeXStudio issue.

Comment: Your image seemed to show that "Could not start the command: Compile" was the first thing that happened.  Your later edit that your log just has badboxes is completely different, and implies that compiling has already started and possibly finished.  Can you please clarify what error you're seeing (copy and paste, please) and when you're seeing that error?

Comment: When i click f5 to compile, the process doesnt want to start... and show: "Error: Could not start the command: Compile & View". Btw, the badboxes meens nothing... I ll edit to show my screen...

Comment: The log file you see is probably old. Did you change the texmaker settings? It can't find the latex program, one reason could be that you deinstalled miktex or texlive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same problem twice with TeXstudio 3.0.3. The only way I found to solve this problem in Windows 10 was to reinstall TeXstudio.

Comment: thanks! Actually, I did it many times but i don't know why the problem still persists! But now I am just using overleaf... 0 problems...